Python mplfinance plot error: "x and y must be the same size"
Trying to plot trades (buy=green, sell=red) on top of the candlestick chart. If I plot all trades all-together works, but when I try to plot them separating by trade side it throws the:
ValueError("x and y must be the same size")

Can't really understand why I'm having this error. Trade data is merged together with the price movement (I've tried separated with the same result).
Buys:
DateTime                                                                                                                             
2020-05-27 04:00:00  0.66460  0.66490  0.66379  0.66393  Market  0.66393  Buy  20000.0  Executed  2020-05-27 04:00:00         0.66398
2020-05-27 13:00:00  0.66165  0.66226  0.65776  0.65840  Market  0.65840  Buy  20000.0  Executed  2020-05-27 13:00:00         0.65845
2020-05-29 16:00:00  0.66408  0.66482  0.66237  0.66418  Market  0.66418  Buy  20000.0  Executed  2020-05-29 16:00:00         0.66423
2020-06-03 10:00:00  0.69049  0.69070  0.68725  0.68725  Market  0.68725  Buy  20000.0  Executed  2020-06-03 10:00:00         0.68730
2020-06-04 02:00:00  0.68986  0.69034  0.68923  0.68976  Market  0.68976  Buy  20000.0  Executed  2020-06-04 02:00:00         0.68981
2020-06-05 19:00:00  0.69686  0.69699  0.69604  0.69643  Market  0.69643  Buy  20000.0  Executed  2020-06-05 19:00:00         0.69648

Sells:
Sells:                          Open     High      Low    Close    Type    Price  Side     Size    Status                 Date  Executed Price
DateTime                                                                                                                              
2020-05-25 00:00:00  0.65461  0.65509  0.65376  0.65397  Market  0.65397  Sell  10000.0  Executed  2020-05-25 00:00:00         0.65397
2020-05-27 09:00:00  0.66505  0.66754  0.66415  0.66752  Market  0.66752  Sell  20000.0  Executed  2020-05-27 09:00:00         0.66752
2020-05-28 06:00:00  0.66119  0.66297  0.66079  0.66235  Market  0.66235  Sell  20000.0  Executed  2020-05-28 06:00:00         0.66235
2020-05-29 20:00:00  0.66627  0.66748  0.66627  0.66730  Market  0.66730  Sell  20000.0  Executed  2020-05-29 20:00:00         0.66730
2020-06-03 16:00:00  0.69486  0.69516  0.69357  0.69388  Market  0.69388  Sell  20000.0  Executed  2020-06-03 16:00:00         0.69388
2020-06-04 14:00:00  0.69184  0.69803  0.69138  0.69782  Market  0.69782  Sell  20000.0  Executed  2020-06-04 14:00:00         0.69782

This is my function:
import mplfinance as mpf
import pandas as pd

def plotStockEquity(df_stock, trade_data):
    
    if 'Date' in df_stock.columns and 'Time' in df_stock.columns:
        df_stock['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_stock['Date'] + ' ' + df_stock['Time'])
        df_stock.set_index('DateTime', inplace=True)
        df_stock.drop(['Date', 'Time'], axis=1, inplace=True)

    # Process trade data for annotations
    df_trades = pd.DataFrame(trade_data)
    df_trades['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_trades['Date'])
    df_trades.set_index('DateTime', inplace=True)
    df_trades['Executed Price'] = pd.to_numeric(df_trades['Executed Price'], errors='coerce')
    
    # Merge the stock data with the trades data
    df_merged = df_stock.merge(df_trades, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)

    # Filter out rows where trades occurred
    buys = df_merged[df_merged['Side'] == 'Buy']
    sells = df_merged[df_merged['Side'] == 'Sell']

    # Create a figure and plot the data
    apd = mpf.make_addplot(buys['Executed Price'], type='scatter', markersize=200, marker='^', color='green')
    apd2 = mpf.make_addplot(sells['Executed Price'], type='scatter', markersize=200, marker='v', color='red')

    # Plot using mplfinance
    mpf.plot(df_merged, type='candle', style='charles', addplot=[apd, apd2], volume=False, title='Stock Price Chart with Buy/Sell Signals')

I've already invested 3 days into this, but can't really figure it out.

Based on my experience having similar errors, I would say that the most likely culprit is that one or more of your mpf.make_addplot() calls contains a different number of datapoints than the dataframe passed into mpf.plot().  Check the number of datapoints being passed into each make_addplot() call, and in your dataframe in plot().
That said, as  a general rule when debugging, it is important to know from where in the code a message is coming.  This is always key.  You need to show the entire traceback (not just the error message ValueError("x and y must be the same size")) so that we can see where the message is coming from.
